# size of pointers and architecture

Tags: c++, c, assembly, portability

By conducting a basic test by running a simple C++ program on a normal desktop PC it seems plausible to suppose that sizes of pointers of any type (including pointers to functions) are equal to the target architecture bits ?

For example: in 32 bits architectures -> 4 bytes and in 64 bits architectures -> 8 bytes.

However I remember reading that, it is not like that in general!

So I was wondering what would be such circumstances?

- For equality of size of pointers to data types compared with  size of pointers 
  to other data types
- For equality of size of pointers to data types compared with size of pointers 
  to functions
- For equality of size of pointers to target architecture

Comment: On some architectures, not all pointers are the same size.  Clearly two different sizes can't both be equal to the same "architecture size".  PIC typically has 8 bit data pointer with 14 bit function pointer.  16-bit x86 had 16-bit near and 32-bit far pointers.

Comment: If your computers architecture used bank switched memory, a pointer may be comprised of two portions: a bank and an address into the bank.  If your architecture used segmented memory, a "far" address may be comprised of a segment and offset, and a "near" address may just have an offset.  A function pointer may be different from a data pointer in size, and a member pointer may have non-trivial implementation details making it possibly x2 or x3 larger than the architecture..

Comment: http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Comment: Is this just asking for a "no, you can't assume that"? Or an open-ended list of every situation where the assumption breaks down? Or what?

Comment: @Useless let me just say I am amazed by the answers and comment. Frankly I do not know which one to accept. So I think I will wait to get more answers. But you are right, maybe I should have phrased my question differently. Maybe you can help editing my question.

Comment: Well, what do you want to know? An exhaustive list of every outlier in existence is probably off-topic, and we're unlikely to get it anyway.

Comment: @Useless Well, the question itself is pretty open, but the answer is very simple. "NEVER assume it if the correctness depends on it."

Comment: "target architecture bits" how do you define that?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I was thinking in the line of what we say in general, like 32 bits and 64 bits. Am i wrong?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Right. Modern CPUs support 8, 16, 32 and 64bit general purpose registers. But then you also have stuff like the x87 FPU which uses 80bit registers and MMX, SSE, SSE+, AVX, Neon, etc, which uses up to 512bit registers. Or maybe we are talking about the width of the memory channel? Well, that varies as well. Good comment.

Comment: It appears that there are in fact so many cases of such circumstances that it would be more reasonable no to make the assumption. Further more what is generally referred to by _Architecture_ in term of bits (*E.g.* 64 bits) is just a loosely defined term which might differ greatly from the real _Architecture_ name (*E.g.* x86-64 ). However lets have this post open just as a quick search result for some of the circumstances.

Comment: Keil C51 had 3-byte pointers, for an 8 bit CPU

Comment: @M.M I re edited my question, could you please check if it was a good idea, or should I change it back, since some of answers are quoting  the previous version?

Comment: What OS is this PC running?  (Random examples that will affect this experiment: DOS, Windows 3.x, Windows 95, Windows XP 32-bit, Windows XP 64-bit, ...)

Comment: @EricTowers I agree. It was Linux 64 bits!

Comment: What is guaranteed is what is in the language definition & the compiler/implementation documentation, period.

Comment: It is a reasonable assumption, common 64-bit data models are documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).  If probably [don't want](https://linux.slashdot.org/story/18/12/12/1336210/linux-kernel-developers-discuss-dropping-x32-support) to rely on the exception.

Comment: Another variant I've not seen mentioned yet is "most pointers and the native instruction set are word pointers, char* pointers implemented by the C compiler on top of that are larger because they also have a byte offset", which was (AIUI) how Prime minicomputers worked in the 1980s.

Answer (score 24):

No, it is not reasonable to assume. Making this assumption can cause bugs.

The sizes of pointers (and of integer types) in C or C++ are ultimately determined by the C or C++ implementation. Normal C or C++ implementations are heavily influenced by the architectures and the operating systems they target, but they may choose the sizes of their types for reasons other than execution speed, such as goals of supporting lower memory use (smaller pointers means less memory used in programs with lots of pointers), supporting code that was not written to be fully portable to any type sizes, or supporting easier use of big integers.

I have seen a compiler targeted for a 64-bit system but providing 32-bit pointers, for the purpose of building programs with smaller memory use. (It had been observed that the sizes of pointers were a considerable factor in memory consumption, due to the use of many structures with many connections and references using pointers.) Source code written with the assumption that the pointer size equalled the 64-bit register size would break.

Comment: The compiler you have seen is most likely GCC with [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).

Comment: @Ruslan: No, it was not.

Comment: @Ruslan MSVC also has the ability to [use 32-bit pointers in 64-bit programs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55460361/995714). And on other 64-bit platforms like MIPS, Sparc or PPC it's also common to use 32-bit pointers to save memory, because those architectures don't have a bigger number of registers on the transition to 64-bit like ARM or x86

Comment: Note that the IBM iSeries (AS/400, OS/400) machines use 16-byte pointers.  For example, see the discussion in [Chapter 22: Using OS/400 pointers in a program](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAE4W_9.5.1/com.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc/cpprog440.htm) and also [Chapter 29: Using Teraspace in ILE C and C++ programs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAE4W_9.5.1/com.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc/cpprog588.htm). There are also 8-byte pointer libraries; code compiled for 8-byte pointers can't link with 16-byte pointer libraries and vice versa. (16-byte pointers are 'native'.)

Comment: See also [A close study of i5/OS machine interface (MI) pointers](https://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/rpg/a-close-study-of-i5os-machine-interface-mi-pointers).  It's tough reading, though.

Comment: Many people miss the fact that smaller pointers also means smaller *cache footprint* and less *memory bandwidth* for pointer-heavy data structures like trees and arrays of pointers.  They think computers have lots of RAM so memory usage only matters in terms of running out of RAM with huge data structures.  (Even that isn't a great assumption when multiple programs are running, though, especially in virtual servers with a small VM instance.)

Comment: In most programs it's not a huge effect, and the [ILP32 ABI for x86-64 Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) hasn't caught on.  But for more memory-constrained devices like smartphones, I think there's more uptake of ILP32 ARM64.  (Also the different software ecosystem makes installing ILP32 versions of every library a different problem from on a desktop/laptop Linux.)

Answer (score 16):

> It is reasonable to assume that in general sizes of pointers of any type (including pointers to functions) are equal to the target architecture bits?

Depends. If you're aiming for a quick estimate of memory consumption it can be good enough. But not if your programs correctness depends on it.

> (including pointers to functions)

But here is one important remark. Although most pointers will have the same size, function pointers may differ. It is not guaranteed that a `void*` will be able to hold a function pointer. At least, this is true for C. I don't know about C++.

> So I was wondering what would be such circumstances if any?

It can be tons of reasons why it differs. If your programs correctness depends on this size it is NEVER ok to do such an assumption. Check it up instead. It shouldn't be hard at all.

You can use this macro to check such things at compile time in C:

```
#include <assert.h>
static_assert(sizeof(void*) == 4, "Pointers are assumed to be exactly 4 bytes");
```

When compiling, this gives an error message:

```
$ gcc main.c 
In file included from main.c:1:
main.c:2:1: error: static assertion failed: "Pointers are assumed to be exactly 4 bytes"
 static_assert(sizeof(void*) == 4, "Pointers are assumed to be exactly 4 bytes");
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If you're using C++, you can skip `#include <assert.h>` because `static_assert` is a keyword in C++. (And you can use the keyword `_Static_assert` in C, but it looks ugly, so use the include and the macro instead.)

Since these two lines are so extremely easy to include in your code, there's NO excuse not to do so if your program would not work correctly with the wrong pointer size.

Answer (score 10):

> It is reasonable to assume that in general sizes of pointers of any type (including pointers to functions) are equal to the target architecture bits?

It might be reasonable, but it isn't reliably correct. So I guess the answer is *"no, except when you already know the answer is yes (and aren't worried about portability)"*.

Potentially:

- systems can have different register sizes, and use different underlying widths for data and addressing: it's not apparent what "target architecture bits" even means for such a system, so you have to choose a specific ABI (and once you've done that you know the answer, for that ABI).
- systems may support different pointer models, such as the old `near`, `far` and `huge` pointers; in that case you need to know what mode your code is being compiled in (and then you know the answer, for that mode)
- systems may support different pointer sizes, such as the X32 ABI already mentioned, or either of the other popular 64-bit data models described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Data_models)

Finally, there's no obvious benefit to this assumption, since you can just use `sizeof(T)` directly for whatever `T` you're interested in.

If you want to convert between integers and pointers, use `intptr_t`. If you want to store integers and pointers in the same space, just use a `union`.

Answer (score 8):

Target architecture "bits" says about registers size. Ex. Intel 8051 is 8-bit and operates on 8-bit registers, but (external)RAM and (external)ROM is accessed with 16-bit values.

Comment: This should really be a comment.

Comment: @MamCieNaHita you are right and I just now remembered that the same goes for AVR-8. But from other comments it appears that it is even more complex than that! Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: @fuz The question was asking "what would be circumstances in which the target architecture bit-ness is different from the pointer size". The answer is fine, it's the question that's too open ended IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

For *correctness*, you cannot assume anything. You have to check and be prepared to deal with weird situations.

As a *general* rule of thumb, it is a *reasonable* default *assumption*.

It's not universally true though. See the [X32 ABI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI), for example, which uses 32bit pointers on 64bit architectures to save a bit of memory and cache footprint.  Same for the ILP32 ABI on AArch64.

So, for guesstimating memory use, you can use your assumption and it will often be right.

Comment: PAE isn't relevant to C++ programming on any existing C++ implementation.  It doesn't increase the size of virtual address space, only physical.  And it only works when paging is enabled, so in a hypothetical freestanding C++ program that runs with paging disabled it's no help in addressing more than 4GB of physical memory.

Comment: @JesperJuhl There are way too many architectures (e.g., base & displacement pointers) and language systems (e.g. LISP) where pointers to different types are of different lengths. If you include pointers-to-functions, as OP explicitly did, There are several cases where the size of the pointer depends on the number of paramaters passed and the return value of the function. This is a bad assumption for any portability intention, and can get you in deep before you realize the problems. Your answer's last two sentences should be the first two.

Comment: @mpez0 I know. And yes, of course it's a bad assumption for portability, which is why I *explicitly* said that it was an ok assumption for guesstimating memory use, but useless for correctness.

Comment: @mpez0 - "Your answer's last two sentences should be the first two" - better now?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, better, thanks. I would only regard different sized pointers "weird" if you're regarding anything but Algol family languages on recent x86 architectures as "weird." However, that's a fairly common viewpoint and set of default assumptions. It'll work, until it doesn't, and then it will be a big mystery to clean up.

Answer (score 5):

> It is reasonable to assume that in general sizes of pointers of any type (including pointers to functions) are equal to the target architecture bits?

If you look at all types of CPUs (including microcontrollers) currently being produced, I would say no.

Extreme counterexamples would be architectures where **two different** pointer sizes are used in the **same program**:

**x86, 16-bit**

In MS-DOS and 16-bit Windows, a "normal" program used both 16- and 32-bit pointers.

**x86, 32-bit segmented**

There were only a few, less known operating systems using this memory model.

Programs typically used both 32- and 48-bit pointers.

**STM8A**

This modern automotive 8-bit CPU uses 16- and 24-bit pointers. Both in the same program, of course.

**AVR tiny series**

RAM is addressed using 8-bit pointers, Flash is addressed using 16-bit pointers.

(However, AVR tiny cannot be programmed with C++, as far as I know.)

Comment: GCC has an AVR back-end; I assume you can at least compile a function using `std::` algorithms, if not containers that do dynamic allocation.

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, the 8086 didn't really have 32-bit pointers, which would have allowed a 4 Gbyte address space.  It had 24-bit FAR pointers in a segmented address space, where each offset addressed 64K bytes (the same as a NEAR pointer), and the segment register allowed a segment to start on any 256 byte boundary in memory, giving the 1 MByte of address space.

Comment: @jamesqf The segment registers on x86 are 16 bits wide, not 8 bits. So a 16-bit `far` pointer is 32 bits in size. In "real mode" (8086) segments can be aligned on any 16-byte boundary. And the segmented addresses 0x7C0:0 and 0x0:7C00 point to the same byte in RAM but they have a different meaning when being used as code pointers.

Comment: @Martin Rosenau: Yes.  Maybe my comment wasn't clear: the segment:offset register pair occupies 32 bits, but because of the way they're implemented, they only allow for a 24-bit address space.  (And if memory serves, you had to manipulate segment & offset registers separately at the assembly level.)

Comment: @jamesqf It depends. In "real mode" (8086 mode) (2^20)+(2^16)-16 **data** bytes can be accessed in memory. This means that there are effectively less than 21 address bits. Hypothetically, an 8086 has 2^32 addresses for **code** that **cannot** be substituted. This means that **every** of these 2^32 addresses has a different meaning and cannot be replaced by another address! This means that code pointers are really effectively 32-bits wide on a 8086. 16-bit code running on a 80386 can address more than 2^29 data bytes, so the effective address width is 30 bits using 16:16 segmented addressing.

Answer (score 4):

It's not correct, for example DOS pointers (16 bit) can be far (seg+ofs).

However, for the usual targets (Windows, OSX, Linux, Android, iOS) then it's correct. Because they all use the flat programming model which relies on paging.

In theory, you can also have systems which uses only the lower 32 bits when in x64. An example is a Windows executable linked without LARGEADDRESSAWARE. However this is to help the programmer avoid bugs when switching to x64. The pointers are truncated to 32 bits, but they are still 64 bit.

In x64 operating systems then this assumption is always true, because the flat mode is the only valid one. Long mode in CPU forces GDT entries to be 64 bit flat.

One also mentions a x32 ABI, I believe it is based on the same paging technology, forcing all pointers to be mapped to the lower 4gb.  However this must be based to the same theory as in Windows. In x64 you can only have flat mode.

In 32 bit protected mode you could have pointers up to 48 bits. (Segmented mode). You can also have callgates. But, no operating system uses that mode.

Comment: x86 32-bit protected mode is used by every 32-bit x86 OS.  But (almost?) all of them use a flat memory model, which I think is the point you're making.  Anyway yes, a seg:off "far" pointer would take 6 bytes in protected mode, but you still only have 4GB of actual addressable memory.  Segment base + offset produces a 32-bit linear address.  With paging disabled it's a 32-bit physical address.  With paging enabled, it's a 32-bit virtual address.  PAE can let separate processes each use a separate 4GB of physical memory at the same time by translating 32-bit virtual to 36-bit physical addresses.

Comment: The Linux x32 ABI and other ILP32 ABIs in general don't necessarily require paging.  You could in theory have an OS that loads position-independent code at different physical addresses within the low 32 bits of physical address space.

Comment: Nitpick: long mode ignores the base/limit in GDT entries selected by segments other than FS/GS, rather than requiring them to be `0` / `-1`.  And "mapped" is the wrong word for ensuring all pointers are in the low 4GB, that phrasing seems to imply arbitrary virtual addresses mapped to  the low 4GB of physical memory.  (And BTW, it's actually the low 2GB of virtual address space, so zero- and sign- extension of 32-bit absolute pointers are both valid.  e.g. `mov edi, array` (zero-extended immediate) or `add rax, [array + rcx]` (sign extended disp32) can both be used for static addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, on microcomputers and microcontrollers, pointers were often wider than general-purpose registers so that the CPU could address enough memory and still fit within the transistor budget.  Most 8-bit CPUs (such as the 8080, Z80 or 6502) had 16-bit addresses.

Today, a mismatch is more likely to be because an app doesn’t need multiple gigabytes of data, so saving four bytes of memory on every pointer is a win.

Both C and C++ provide separate `size_t`, `uintptr_t` and `off_t` types, representing the largest possible object size (which might be smaller than the size of a pointer if the memory model is not flat), an integral type wide enough to hold a pointer, and a file offset (often wider than the largest object allowed in memory), respectively.  A `size_t` (unsigned) or `ptrdiff_t` (signed) is the most portable way to get the native word size.  Additionally, POSIX guarantees that the system compiler has some flag that means a `long` can hold any of these, but you cannot always assume so.

Comment: Any reason you left out signed `intptr_t`?  Anyway, worth pointing out that `[u]intptr_t` can hold any pointer, while `size_t` only has to hold the max object size.  On a machine without a flat memory model, these can easily be different widths.  e.g. on x86-16 with far pointers being possible, `uintptr_t` has to be 32-bit, but `size_t` can be 16-bit.

Comment: (Note that most implementations restrict object size to SIZE_MAX/2 or less, so `ptrdiff_t` can't overflow with char arrays.)  [Why is the maximum size of an array "too large"?](//stackoverflow.com/a/42594384)

Comment: `off_t` is for *file* sizes / positions.  It can be and often is 64-bit on a purely 32-bit system, and mentioning it here makes zero sense.  Also, none of the types you mentioned are guaranteed to find the max register width, though: a modern ILP32 ABI on a 64-bit architecture will typically have 32-bit `size_t`, `uintptr_t`, and `ptrdiff_t`.  So if you use that to decide if the machine has efficient `long long` / `uint64_t`, you'll incorrectly rule out x32 on x86-64 and ILP32 on AArch64, for example.  You could additionally check `#ifdef __SIZEOF_INT128__` because GCC defines that on 64-bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don’t think we disagree. I mentioned only `uintptr_t` because it’s exactly the same width as the signed counterpart, and the other two types are unsigned.

Comment: @PeterCordes `uintptr_t` doesn't have to be anything, it is an optional type

Comment: @PeterCordes I have no idea where you’re getting any of that. Please take another look at what I wrote. I stated that a `uintptr_t` is an integral type wide enough to hold a pointer and that an `off_t` is a file offset.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that was just the start of a very long sentence.  If you stop and think at the first parens, it's easy to assume that's going to be the end of the sentence and that you're saying all 3 of those types are provided to represent object size.  It's correct but the readability / skimmability isn't great.

Answer (score 0):

Generally pointers will be size 2 on a 16-bit system, 3 on a 24-bit system, 4 on a 32-bit system, and 8 on a 64-bit system. It depends on the [ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348010/3648282) and C implementation. AMD has [long and legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes) modes, and there are [differences between AMD64 and Intel64 for Assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Differences_between_AMD64_and_Intel_64) programmers but these are hidden for higher level languages.

Any problems with C/C++ code is likely to be due to poor programming practices and ignoring compiler warnings. See: "[20 issues of porting C++ code to the 64-bit platform](https://www.viva64.com/en/a/0004/)".

See also: "[Can pointers be of different sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15832631/3648282)" and [LRiO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832939/3648282):

> ... you are asking about C++ and its compliant implementations, not some specific physical machine. I'd have to quote the entire standard in order to **prove it**, but the simple fact is that it makes no guarantees on the result of sizeof(T*) for any T, and (as a corollary) no guarantees that sizeof(T1*) == sizeof(T2*) for any T1 and T2).

Note: **Where** is [answered by JeremyP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520921/3648282), C99 section 6.3.2.3, subsection 8:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined.

In GCC you can avoid incorrect assumptions by using built-in functions: "[Object Size Checking Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html)":

> Built-in Function: size_t __builtin_object_size (const void * ptr, int type)
>
> is a built-in construct that returns a constant number of bytes from ptr to the end of the object ptr pointer points to (if known at compile time). To determine the sizes of dynamically allocated objects the function relies on the allocation functions called to obtain the storage to be declared with the alloc_size attribute (see Common Function Attributes). __builtin_object_size never evaluates its arguments for side effects. If there are any side effects in them, it returns (size_t) -1 for type 0 or 1 and (size_t) 0 for type 2 or 3. If there are multiple objects ptr can point to and all of them are known at compile time, the returned number is the maximum of remaining byte counts in those objects if type & 2 is 0 and minimum if nonzero. If it is not possible to determine which objects ptr points to at compile time, __builtin_object_size should return (size_t) -1 for type 0 or 1 and (size_t) 0 for type 2 or 3.

Comment: The differences between Intel64 and AMD64 are very minor and totally irrelevant to discussion of pointer widths.  They're pretty much limited to a few kernel system-management differences; normal computation is identical across all x86-64; that's why we don't need separate binaries for Intel vs. AMD CPUs.

Comment: You're assuming that `CHAR_BIT` is defined as 8.  A 24-bit system is probably a DSP with 24-bit word-addressable memory, so a `char` is probably also 24-bit.  Thus `sizeof()` everything = 1.

Comment: What did you say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399003/3648282) or in the Q&As I linked to?

Comment: What did *I* say?  I haven't commented on or answered that linked question, no idea what point you're making.  Maybe you mean that a 24-bit system might not have 24-bit pointers; that's certainly possible, a C++ implementation is allowed to exist where some or all kinds of pointers are wider than its 24-bit char/int.  But I meant for a "normal" 24-bit DSP, it probably wouldn't have byte-addressable memory with 3-byte "words", so a normal C++ implementation on it would probably have `sizeof(void*) = sizeof(int*) = sizeof(char) = sizeof(int) = 1`.